# JavaScript, Redux, React. Does it possible to prevent default location reload ?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have a route localhost:8080/ and I use Redux to store states in my React App.

On first start app, I have a login page, when I log in, I change state and got an App with routes, but if I focus url address bar and press enter it reloads Redux state and kick me back to login page like I am not authorized.

(I suppose that I can preventDefault actions for Enter button using its keycode === 13, but how about location.reload exactly)

Can I prevent this behavior of location.reload on Enter  ?

Comment: Can you please post enough of your code to provide an example?

Comment: Redux state is stored in memory, so on refresh, it doesn't save your state. Try using redux-persist: https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

Comment: I think instead of stopping browser to reload, you want to set browser cookies so that session persists

Comment: @notgiorgi@lavish@Chad thanks guys, I use locationStorage and will try redux-presist

Comment: it should be localStorage, not locationStorage.

Comment: @fungusanthrax I`ve just made a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you want the page to stop reloading on login, then yes as you've said, just use `event.preventDefault();`

But If what you're asking is how to prevent the page from reloading when a user presses enter on the address bar. I don't think there is any way to prevent this, sorry. It's a limitation you can only bypass if you have control of the browser.